# Change game from portrait to landscape dynamically

Tags: java, android, libgdx, orientation

I have multiple classes that implement `Screen`.

I want to, say, have the **Main Menu** screen `portrait`, then the **Play Screen** `landscape`. Is there anyway of changing the `orientation` dynamically?

I thought I could just start another `Activity` and have the **Play Screen** extend `Game`. And the new `Activity` would `intialize` the **Play Screen**. But it appears that you can't call `startActivity` or the like, obviously, as `LibGDX` is platform independent.

I use `Gdx.graphics.getWidth()` and `Gdx.graphics.getHeight()` to align `Sprites` and `Actors` so it looks "right" on different devices.

I've also tried swapping the `Gdx.graphics.getWidth()` and `Gdx.graphics.getHeight()`, respectively, but can't seem to get the position of sprites and actors correct.

Comment: May be useful check below link http://stackoverflow.com/a/37568617/3445320

Answer (score 1):

I figured out how to do it.

I used an interface as shown at this [link](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Interfacing-with-platform-specific-code)

Basically, I created an interface in the core project, then for each back-end project I `implements` my interface.

To change the `orientation` in Android is simple as shown [here](http://android-er.blogspot.in/2011/08/set-screen-orientation-programmatically.html)

That is, `setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.<THE_ORIENTATION>)`

Comment: This answer would be better if it included the relevant code, so that even if the two links break the information is preserved.